# Unexpected error when connecting to ES cluster using SniffingConnectionPool

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am getting the following error when connecting with the ES cluster using SniffingConnectionPool in C#.

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'nodes.ZfZk0Y0PQWqg_dkfJZ9DSg.settings['discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts']', line 1, position 439.

Its clearly related to JSON parsing but I am not sure how to get around with this. Any help will be highly appreciated

Here's how I configured my cluster:

```
Master Node Config:

cluster.name: elasticsearch_marvel
node.name: "Wolverine"
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: 192.168.1.9
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.1.10:9300"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

Data Node Config:

cluster.name: elasticsearch_marvel
node.name: "Deadpool"
node.master: false
node.data: true
network.host: 192.168.1.10
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.1.9:9300"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

And here's how I am trying to connect to the cluster:

```
    public ElasticClient CreateClient(IEnumerable<Uri> uris)
    {
        var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(uris);
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        return client;
    }

    public bool TestConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            var uris = new List<Uri>();
            uris.Add(new Uri("http://192.168.1.9:9200/"));
            uris.Add(new Uri("http://192.168.1.10:9200/"));
            var client = CreateClient(uris);
            var response = client.Ping();
            return response.IsValid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'nodes.ZfZk0Y0PQWqg_dkfJZ9DSg.settings['discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts']', line 1, position 439.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I finally figured this out, value of discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts shouldn't be enclosed in square brackets for NEST elastic search client to work. On changing it to discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: "192.168.1.9:9300" it just works fine. It's kind of weird that ES works just fine when 192.168.1.9:9300 is enclosed within ["192.168.1.9:9300"]  but NEST library throws a JSON serialization exception

Comment: What version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: @RussCam I am using elasticsearch-6.2.4 and Nest v5.3.0.

Comment: Please use NEST 6.x (latest 6.1.0) with Elasticsearch 6.2.4. This should not be an issue with NEST 6.x